# cannot find the module 'id'

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-services

Here I'm getting the error cannot find the name 'id' in service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class AppService {
 coins= [
   {id=1,name='ajay'},
   {id=2, name='venkatesh'}
];
  constructor() { }
  getMyItems(){
  return this.coins;
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `{ id: 1, name: 'ajay' }`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using invalid JSON, it should be,

```
 coins= [
   {id:1,name:'ajay'},
   {id:2, name:'venkatesh'}
];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 coins= [
   {'id':1,'name':'ajay'},
   {'id':2, 'name':'venkatesh'} 

]
```

Comment: Code only answers can almost always be improved with some explanation. Please edit the answer to point out the change you made; the switch from `it=1` to `'id':1`, and maybe explain the syntax as well?